# Mysql database lost on AWS Server Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am using aws server for my web hosting   that uses ubuntu server but after few months i checked the server again all files are there but no database present in phpmyadmin.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the particular user that you are using to login to phpmyadmin don't have enough permission. Try to login with a user with adequate permissions.

Comment: No it didn't happened ever before, But this time only. If there is any permission problem it should not work before, Secondly i check my server by going through folder and files of the mysql directory, its also not present there.

Comment: How did you go. Have you taken any instance backups